# Gadfly: open stacked plots directly in browser?

Tags: julia, gadfly

With Gadfly it is possible to combine plots in a grid and save the combined plot in a file:

```
using Gadfly, Compose

x=1:0.1:5;
grid = Array(Compose.Context, (2, 2));
grid[1,1] = render(plot( x=x, y = x, Geom.line));
grid[1,2] = render(plot( x=x, y = x.^2, Geom.line));
grid[2,1] = render(plot( x=x, y = log(x), Geom.line));
grid[2,2] = render(plot( x=x, y = sqrt(x), Geom.line));
draw(SVG("example.svg", 100mm, 100mm),  gridstack(grid));
```

I wrote a function that creates such a plot and this function creates a file. It is a little bit unintuitive for someone who wants to use this function why exactly this function creates a file, while the results of all the other plotting functions with single plots are displayed directly in the browser.

So, is it possible to call a function (in place of `draw`?) such that the combined plot defined by the grid is displayed directly in the browser like "normal" plots?

Answer (score 3):

```
function as_temp_html(gadflyplot)
    thefilepath=tempname() * ".html"
    write(open(thefilepath,"w"),stringmime("text/html",gadflyplot))
    return thefilepath
end
```

You can open this file in your browser by re-using [Gadfly's crossplatform "open_file" method](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/Gadfly.jl#L1025):

```
function open_file(filename)
    if is_apple()
        run(`open $(filename)`)
    elseif is_linux() || is_bsd()
        run(`xdg-open $(filename)`)
    elseif is_windows()
        run(`$(ENV["COMSPEC"]) /c start $(filename)`)
    else
        warn("Showing plots is not supported on OS $(string(Compat.KERNEL))")
    end
end
```

EDIT: now the answer uses Gadfly-exclusive code

Comment: Thanks. OK, so there seems to be no other option than to create a temporary html file and open it in the browser myself. I found that Gadfly has the almost identical mechanism for this (see https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/Gadfly.jl). I will accept your answer if you change the `open_browser_window` function to the `open_file` function of Gadfly and replace the link to the Plots package with a link the Gadfly repository. It doesn't really make sense to use one plotting package to display the plot of another plotting package, if the functionality is provided there as well.

Comment: well there are tools for doing the same without writing to disk (process pipes, websockets), but as far as I know these haven't been worked to do what you're asking for (live-editing-and-update code-and-plots or fetch-updated-resunt-from-the-browser). Take a look at [Interact.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Interact.jl), though... might become useful